# Set sort Order of Customer Dashboard Custom Tab

Tags: php, magento

I have created a Custom Tab in Customer Account Dashboard. using my custom module layout file.

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
                <name>custom page</name>
                    <path>orders/accountpage/</path>
                    <label>View Old Orders</label>
            </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Now I want to set sort order of this created tab. can anyone someone tell me that how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Karan,Magento did not `have this type of function`,So you need to `customization`.

on  Class `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation`
goto function addLik Modify  code,...

```
public function addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array(),$sort=50)
{
    $this->_links[$name] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'name' => $name,
        'path' => $path,
        'label' => $label,
        'url' => $this->getUrl($path, $urlParams),
        'sort'=> $sort
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

add

```
public function getLinks()
{


$people=$this->_links;

$sortArray = array();

foreach($people as $person){
    foreach($person as $key=>$value){
        if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){
            $sortArray[$key] = array();
        }
        $sortArray[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

$orderby = "sort"; //change this to whatever key you want from the array

array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_DESC,$people);
return $people;

}
```

xml

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
                <name>custom page</name>
                    <path>orders/accountpage/</path>
                    <label>View Old Orders</label>
            <sort>15</sort>
            </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Comment: array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_DESC,$people); is not working